# Make FindBugs settings global and test for all bugs besides some

Tags: maven, findbugs

I work in a team and we use FindBugs as Eclipse plugin. We don't have much experience with this tool yet, so we decided to let FindBugs search for ALL bugs (so we checkmarked all boxes in the Detector configuration). From time to time we decide to uncheck some and so on...

First, it would be nice to have these things global. I think the only way to achieve this is to have a include file filter in which we match ALL bugs and an exclude filter in which we match those bugs that doesn't interest us. Would that work? What happens if i explicitly include and exclude a bug code for example? How can I match all bugs? I can't write the complete list of bug codes... And it would be nice when the Settings under Detector configuration would be ignored to achieve that all work with the same settings.

Comment: We use just an exclude filter in our projects, but I'm not aware of a global settings file. Both Eclipse and the `pom.xml` point to the same filter. That doesn't work for you?

Comment: That does work and it is what we do now. But one problem still is, that all users must have the same checkmarks in the eclipse properties as default. If one unchecks some, FindBugs won't search for this bugs. But I think one has to live with that, that's why the maven plugin is essential...